# why is different between model.evaluate() and computed loss by myself based on model.predict()?

Tags: keras, neural-network, predict, evaluate

I am running neural network by keras. There is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras import Model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import backend as K


def mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
   return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true),axis=-1)

np.random.seed(1)
Train_X = np.random.randint(low=0,high=100,size = (50,5))
Train_Y = np.matmul(Train_X,np.arange(10).reshape(5,2))+np.random.randint(low=0,high=10,size=(50,2))
Test_X = np.random.randint(low=0,high=100,size = (10,5))
Test_Y = np.matmul(Test_X,np.arange(10).reshape(5,2))+np.random.randint(low=0,high=10,size=(10,2))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4,activation = 'relu')) 
model.add(Dense(2,activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(2,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.compile(loss=mean_squared_error, optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])

history = model.fit(Train_X, Train_Y, epochs=100, batch_size=5,validation_data = (Test_X, Test_Y)) 

loss1 = model.evaluate(Test_X,Test_Y)
loss2 = history.history['val_loss'][99]

y_pred = model.predict(Test_X)
y_true = Test_Y
loss3 = np.mean(np.square(y_pred-y_true))
```

I find that `loss1` is the same as `loss2` but is different with `loss3`. So i feel so confused. Could someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly due to different dtypes for `Test_Y` and `y_pred`. Keras tries to automatically take care of dtype mismatches for you, so it is possible that `Test_Y` is a float64 and `y_pred` is a float32. If that is indeed the case, try converting one of their dtypes for the `loss3` calculation and see if the values match.

```
y_pred = model.predict(Test_X)
y_true = Test_Y.astype(np.float32)
loss3 = np.mean(np.square(y_pred-y_true))
```